# Прерывание и крокозябры

Tags: прерывания, ассемблер

Здравствуйте, возникло несколько проблем при написании программы на assembler'e.

1. Что за прерывание mov ah, 9? И прерывание ли это вообще?
2. Последняя процедура не выводит 3 строки, а точнее выводит, но крокозябры. Почему?

Если написать mov ah, 02h вообще ничего не выведет.

```
 .model tiny    
     org 100h

     .data            
     chislo1 db ?          
     mess0 db "",0ah,0dh,'$'
     mess db "Vvedite chislo1: ",'$'  
     message dw "HELLO, WORLD!", '$'
     message1 dw "MY NAME IS EUGENE!", '$'
     message2 dw "I'M 18 YEARS OLD!", '$'
     .code

     start: 
     mov ax,@data 
     mov ds,ax 
     xor ax, ax

     mov dx, "P"

     mov cx,5
     cikl5:           
      call procedure1                         
     loop cikl5

     ;-----------------------------| 
     mov ah,9 
     mov dx,offset mess 
     int 21h

     mov ah,01h 
     int 21h

     mov chislo1,al

     mov ah,9     
     mov dx,offset mess0 
     int 21h

     mov cx,2
     cicl2:
      call procedure2   
     loop cicl2

     ;-----------------------------|

     push [message2]
     push [message1]
     push [message]

     call procedure3

     ;-----------------------------|

     mov ax,4c00h 
     int 21h

     procedure1 proc 
     mov ah,02h  
     int 21h             
     ret
     procedure1 endp

     procedure2 proc
     mov ah,02h 
     mov dl,chislo1 
     int 21h
     ret
     procedure2 endp

     procedure3 proc

     push bp
     mov bp,sp

      mov ah,9
     mov dx,[bp+2]   
     int 21h

     mov ax,[bp+4]
     mov ah,9
     int 21h

     mov ax,[bp+6]
     mov ah,9
     int 21h

     pop bp   
     ret 6
     procedure3 endp

     end start
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Прерывание 21h](http://assembler-src.blogspot.ru/2010/04/21h-dos.html). mov ah, 9 - это не прерывание, это выбор функции №9 прерывания 21h
2. Адрес строки нужно указывать в регистре dx, что и сделано в procedure3 в первый раз, но во второй и третий раз адрес записывается в ax, а в dx остается неизвестно что ("мусор"), отсюда и кракозябры. [Garbage in – garbage out](http://universal_ru_en.academic.ru/8970/%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5).
3. mov ah, 02h - функция №2 прерывания 21h выводит одиночный символ, код которого записан в регистре DL. Если вы хотели этой функцией вывести целую строку, то вы не получите то, чего ожидали.

Comment: Cпасибо большое,разобрался!